# my ipod touch wont turn on? what do i do?

Tags: ipod-touch

today as i was playing a game on my ipod touch, i used assistive touch to get out of the app since my home button was jammed, but it was acting slow, so i pressed lock screen on the assistive touch and now it wont turn on at all
i tried hard reset but nothing turns on at all !! and plus the screen is cracked, and i dont know what to do right now i had all my good photos and apps and music on it.. when i plugged the usb in the charger, it says its charging but nothing showed up at all

Answer (score 1):

On my old iPod I took about 20 minutes until it booted again if the battery was fully drained.
How long did you wait while it was in the charger?